# Could you take a point on the surface of the earth as the frame of reference in the Hafele-Keating experiment?

Tags: general-relativity, special-relativity, spacetime, time

I was recently reading about the Hafele-Keating experiment and asking, how does time in the plane which has flow westwards could have passed faster than on the surface of the earth if the frame of reference was here. It was then I realised that the frame of reference in the experiment was chosen to be the center of the earth. But now I'm asking what would have happened, if one really chose the frame of reference to be on the surface of earth. Then, the plane should have had a velocity greater than that of the inertial observer on the surface of the earth in both direction (in one even greater due to earth's rotation) and time should have passed in both situations slower with reference to the observer on the surface of the earth. I'm not sure if these assumptions are correct, as I've just started to learn SRT on my own.

Answer (score 1):

> But now I'm asking what would have happened, if one really chose the frame of reference to be on the surface of earth.

The calculations would have been more complicated.

The principle of relativity guarantees that we will get the same experimental predictions regardless of which frame we use. So we are free to use whichever frame makes the calculations easiest, knowing that we will always get the same experimental predictions.

> the plane should have had a velocity greater than that of the inertial observer on the surface of the earth in both direction (in one even greater due to earth's rotation) and time should have passed in both situations slower with reference to the observer on the surface of the earth.

The frame of the surface of the earth is not an inertial frame. In that frame time dilation is more complicated. It does not pass slower in both directions.

Comment: Thank you for your response. My mistake was to assume that the surface of the earth is an inertial system because I thought rotation could be regarded as "uniform movement", which is not the case.